# CalendarContract.ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER get called multiple times

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-calendar

I have a receiver to catch events. Here is my receiver:

```
public class CalendarReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(CalendarContract.ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER)) {
            Log.d("test", "reminder fired");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `manifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name=".CalendarReminderReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The problem is the log appears in logcat multiple times (six times). I tested on lollipop and kitkat and in both devices receiver fired 6 times. What is the problem?